# Making two percentage divs responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two divs that have the width of 45% each right next to each other.

```
<div class="rightbox"> text </div><div class="leftbox"> text </div>


.rightbox {
margin-top:40px;
border:1px solid red;
float:right;
width:45%;
height:500px;
background-color:rgba(155,195,207,1);
}

.leftbox {
margin-top:40px;
border:1px solid black;
float:left;
width:45%;
height:500px;
background-color:rgba(155,195,207,1);
}
```

How do I make the rightbox responsively drop down below the leftbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `@media` queries for the screen you want to drop the box down responsively.

For example you have to do it after screen of 480 then css should be

```
@media all and (max-width:480px){
    .rightbox, .leftbox{
        float:none;
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

This css will apply only if the screen width is less then or equal to 480px;

> For perfect result on all devices with `@media` queries you need to use viewport meta tag also which detects the screen width then only `@media` queries work fine.

**Meta tag**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```